# Rails update in different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Hello im doing simple update..

**logged_customer_controller.rb**

```
class LoggedCustomerController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authorize
  helper_method :current_customer

  layout "frontend"

  def current_customer
    @current_customer ||= Customer.find(session[:customer_id]) if session[:customer_id]
  end

  def authorize
    if session[:auth] != true
      redirect_to login_path, :notice => "Not logged."
    end
  end

  def show
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if current_customer.update_attributes(params[:current_customer])
        format.html { redirect_to view_path, notice: 'Customer was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: current_customer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

end
```

**routes.rb**

```
  match "view" => "logged_customer#show", :via => :get
  match "edit" => "logged_customer#edit", :via => :get
  match "edit" => "logged_customer#edit", :via => :put
```

**edit.html.erb**

```
    <%= form_for current_customer, :url => url_for(:controller => 'logged_customer', :action => 'edit'), :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>

<% if current_customer.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="alert alert-error">
      The form contains <%= pluralize(current_customer.errors.count, "error") %>.
    </div>
    <ul>
    <% current_customer.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li> <%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>

...
```

I can display localhost:3000/view where is edit button. At localhost:3000/edit the form is displayed with autofilled informations, everything looks good. When i click on submit button im redirected to same edit autofilled form but WITHOUT any error ? So i guess there is some mistake because updating failed and another mistake that it dont render errors. What im doing wrong ?

I have logged_customer_controller.rb because customer_controller.rb is for administration purposes and is under authorization.

at Development.log i have only (looks good)

```
Started PUT "/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-19 14:54:30 +0200
Processing by LoggedCustomerController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {...}
  <Executing SQL ...>
  Rendered logged_customer/edit.html.erb within layouts/frontend (67.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 89ms (Views: 33.0ms | ActiveRecord: 56.0ms)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, on your `form_for` you say that the action is the `edit` one, when it should be `update`.

```
<%= form_for current_customer, 
  :url => url_for(:controller => 'logged_customer', :action => 'edit'), 
  :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
```

This way, when you submit it would hit the edit action. Change this and you are good to go.

Also, change you route as @Mattherick said:

```
match "update" => "logged_customer#update", :via => :put
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your routes (rails 3):

```
match "view" => "logged_customer#show", :via => :get
match "edit" => "logged_customer#edit", :via => :get
match "update" => "logged_customer#update", :via => :put
```

Change your routes (rails 4):

```
get "view" => "logged_customer#show"
get "edit" => "logged_customer#edit"
patch "update" => "logged_customer#update"
```

Change your form:

```
<%= form_for current_customer, :url => url_for(:controller => 'logged_customer', :action => 'update'), :method => "patch", :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
  <%= # your form fields %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: thank you it works, and finally i know difference between match and get :-)